# i want to fetch array of record in xml using c# Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

this is my code to fetch xml values from files and it does successfully but single element like an in file type but when i try to fetch array of records from xml it failed

```
public void readXmlFiles()
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Applications\Files\Xmldemo.xml");
        var format = from r in xml.Descendants("insureance")
                     select new
                     {
                         type = r.Element("type").Value,
                        // values=r.Element("value").Value

                     };

        foreach (var r in format)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.values);
        }

    }
```

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<insureance>
  <type>Risk</type>
  <classofbusiness type="array">
    <value>0</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
  </classofbusiness>
</insureance>
```

now i want to fetch classofbusiness all values thanx in advance

Comment: What's insureance? Also, what is your expected behavior, and what's it currently doing? "It failed" is not very descriptive.

Comment: sorry it was insurance and im try to fetch records from xml i successfully fetch type ie RISK but could not able to classofbusiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current attempt selects a single `value` element, which doesn't exist as a child of `insureance`. I would guess you get a null reference exception as a result.

You need to follow the structure of the document

```
var format =
    from ins in doc.Descendants("insureance")
    select new
    {
        Type = (string) ins.Element("type"),
        ClassOfBusiness = ins.Elements("classofbusiness")
            .Elements("value")
            .Select(x => (int) x)
            .ToArray()
    };
```

Comment: how to store whole records into object

Comment: @user6254141 what does that mean?

Comment: i want store format into one object then pass to the function so that all data will be getting for the particular function

Comment: @user6254141 this does project all the data in the record into an object. There's no more data to put in it. So what are you asking?

Comment: actually i have implemented one function for getting the data from XML and i need to pass to the other function through parameter

Comment: @user6254141 you would need to create a class with the properties you need and project to that (rather than an anonymous type in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
var format = xml.Elements("insureance").Elements("classofbusiness").Descendants();
```